# Obtaining file path of current spec file with shared examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I want to ask what is the acceptable pattern for obtaining the file path of the current spec file and others in the call stack.

For example, I have a few view specs that share a `it_should_behave_like` example, and the `shared_examples_for` is defined in a separate mixin spec.

Imagine:

`views/page1.html_spec.rb`
`views/page2.html_spec.rb`

with

`it_behaves_like "common view"`

and

`mixins/common_view_spec_mixin.rb`

with

`shared_examples_for "common view" do`

If I want to get the spec file calling examples within `mixins/common_view_spec_mixin.rb`, calling

`example.file_path` would yield
`./spec/mixins/common_view_spec_mixin.rb`

but this isn't very helpful if I want to know whether `page1` or `page2` is being tested.

I found I can go into the metadata to dig into the call stack to get the file_paths:

`example.metadata[:example_group][:file_path]` yields `./spec/mixins/common_view_spec_mixin.rb`

and

`example.metadata[:example_group][:example_group][:file_path]` yields `./spec/views/page1.html_spec.rb` or `./spec/views/page2.html_spec.rb`

I want to ask if this is an acceptable pattern in case the structure of `RSpec::Core::Example` changes or if there is a better way to do this.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you post a sample of how you would like to use this assuming we get it via `some_method_call`?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to access this information? In the output of the standard formatters, this information is in the failure message dump. You will see a line like:

> Shared Example Group: "common view" called from ./spec/views/page1.html_spec.rb:14

Notice at the end, it gives the full base example file path and the line number where you called `it_should_behave_like`. And directly under that should be the standard context file location:

> ./spec/mixins/common_view_spec_mixin.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in '

Comment: I want to access it within the specs themselves. The metadata can achieve this but I am just wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing it.